# How can I show a fallback image if no featured image exists in database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show a fallback image in case a property does not have a featured image and am trying to use accessors for that.

```
public $uploads = 'images/';

public function getFeaturedImageAttribute($path){
    return $this->uploads . $path;
}

public function photoPlaceholder(){
    return "https://ibin.co/4C4hfps5SKiw.jpg";
}
```

In my view I have this:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{$prop->featured_image ? $prop-featured_image : $prop->photoPlaceholder()}}" alt="{{$prop->heading}}">
```

Right now I dont have a featured image, but the fallback does not show.

Comment: `$prop-featured_image` ?? should use `->` not `-` TYPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is assuming your provided code is an Eloquent Model.

Based on your accessor/mutator for `featured_image` it will always return `images/`.

If `featured_image` exists in the database as a column then `$path` will be the original value. So you can write a check:

```
public function getFeaturedImageAttribute($path) {
  if ( $path ) {
    return $this->uploads.$path;
  }
  return 'https://ibin.co/4C4hfps5SKiw.jpg';
}
```

Now you don't need `{{ $prop->featured_image ? .. : .. }}` you will only need `{{ $prop->featured_image }}`.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: This is the only answer

Comment: @deSousa while your original question had enough info for me to decipher what you were having issues doesn't mean others will be able to. Including that your problem was within an Eloquent Model and that `featured_image` is a pre-existing column in your database would help other users.